# Qual a diferença entre @PostConstruct e o construtor?

Tags: java, spring, annotation

Qual a diferença de usar a anotação `@PostConstruct` ao invés de utilizar método construtor e suas vantagens? Pergunto baseada nessas duas versões da mesma classe que só se diferenciam por essa anotação.

Antes

```
@Repository
public class OldValidacaoDAO {

    MongoCollection mongoCollection;

    public OldValidacaoDAO() {
        this.mongoCollection = DBSingleton.getJongo().getCollection("validacao_validacoes");
    }
}
```

Depois

```
@Repository
public class ValidacaoDAO {

    MongoCollection mongoCollection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.mongoCollection = DBSingleton.getJongo().getCollection("validacao_validacoes");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao usar frameworks que gerenciam o ciclo de vida de suas classes, como é o caso do Spring, é sempre importante entender que uma instância gerenciada pelo framework não é uma instância qualquer.

Uma instância gerenciada pelo Spring é chamda de ***Spring Bean*** e não é um objeto comum. Ele agora tem superpoderes.

## Instância Comum vs. Spring Bean

Considere a seguinte classe:

```
@Service
public class MeuServico {

    @Autowired MeuDao meuDao;

    public void acao() {
       meuDao.atualizarBanco();
    }

}
```

O que acontece se você criar a classe manualmente?

```
MeuServico meuServico = new MeuServico();
meuServico.acao();
```

O resultado será um `NullPonterException` na linha `meuDao.atualizarBanco()`, pois o atributo `meuDao` estará nulo.

**Um objeto normal não é gerenciado pelo Spring.**

Então, sempre que usar um *Spring Bean* você deve deixar o Spring lhe entregar a instância, seja através de uma anotação, injeção através de XML, etc.

## Construtor vs. Pós-Construtor

Quando o Spring inicia o contexto (*Spring Context*), que contém todos os beans, ele cria instâncias dos *beans* anotados ou declarados na configuração, processa as anotações, injeta as dependências e algumas coisas a mais.

Após inicializar corretamente tudo, ele chama o método que esteja anotado com `@PostConstruct`.

Note que no momento que a instância é criada, não há nada injetado ou inicializado.

Portanto, o código abaixo também resultaria em um `NullPointerException`:

```
@Service
public class MeuServico {

    @Autowired MeuDao meuDao;

    public MeuServico() {
       meuDao.iniciarAlgumaCoisaNoBanco();
    }

}
```

Veja, o Spring não conseguirá injetar `meuDao` antes de instanciar a classe. Portanto em qualquer framework não é possível injetar a dependência ou fazer qualquer outra coisa na classe antes de chamar algum construtor.

A solução é usar o pós-construtor, que permite então executar alguma ação logo após a inicialização do Spring, porém antes do sistema executar alguma ação do usuário.

Comment: Esta edição sugerida na sua resposta, que a meu ver estava correta, foi rejeitada. Acho que é algo pertinente a levar ao meta, não acha? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28277

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de uma classe denominada serviço ser repositório.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Na minha opinião a sua edição era válida e foi rejeitada de forma injusta. O serviço deveria ter `@Service` e o repositório `@Repository`.

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais A edição estava correta. A anotação antiga foi uma confusão minha porque a princípio copiei o seu código da pergunta, mas depois resolvi modificar para melhorar o exemplo e esqueci de atualizar a anotação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa as edições não podem alterar o sentido da resposta do autor. Nesse caso o melhor é deixar comentário. O autor pode ter ideia diferente da sua. Essa edição está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2651/como-lidar-com-usu%C3%A1rio-que-rejeita-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-corretas